# SQL Query to extract the numbers before a specific word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this:

```
String 1: 'Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345'
String 2: 'Random Text 3 Test Text Random'
String 3: 'Random Text 777 Random Text'
```

The output I expect is:

```
String 1: '5.5'
String 2: '3'
String 3: Nothing should output
```

The numbers that should be output always appear before the word Test.

I would like the SQL to be compatible with Microsoft SSMS.

Comment: SSMS is the IDE environment, not the RDBMS. What database engine (and version) are you using?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Telling us you use SSMS is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some, but alarming from a mechanic.

Comment: But I *do* [drive](https://www.sony.com/en/SonyInfo/vision-s/vehicle1.html) a [Sony](https://www.sony.com/en/SonyInfo/vision-s/vehicle2.html) @JoelCoehoorn.

Comment: @ThomA doubtful. That's still a concept car.

Comment: It's tongue in cheek, @JoelCoehoorn , but the point stands; Sony is making cars (now). Maybe switch to Panasonic? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Scalar Function like this (I did this in SQL Server)

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNumberBeforeStringTest
(
    @stringToParse varchar(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @testIndex INT = PATINDEX('%test%', @stringToParse);
    
    IF @testIndex = 0 RETURN NULL;

    SET @stringToParse = REPLACE(REPLACE(@stringToParse, '(',' '), ')','')
    DECLARE @s1 VARCHAR(100) = REVERSE(TRIM(SUBSTRING(@stringToParse, 0, @testIndex)))
    
    DECLARE @s2 VARCHAR(100) = REVERSE(TRIM(SUBSTRING(@s1, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @s1))))

    IF TRY_CAST(@s2 AS decimal) IS NULL
        RETURN NULL;

    RETURN @s2;
END
GO
```

You use like this
***select dbo.GetNumberBeforeStringTest()***

e.g.
**select dbo.GetNumberBeforeStringTest(**'Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345'**)**

Result: 5.5

Comment: Hi @9jaCoder I've noticed that when there is a string with brackets and a floating point the function doesn't work. An example would be: 'Random Text (3.9 Test) Text Random'. Would it be possible to tell me how to edit the function to also be able to extract the number from a string in this format too? Or would this need to be a new question? Thanks

Comment: @LloydThomas Add this before the line "DECLARE @s1..."

`SET @stringToParse = REPLACE(REPLACE(@stringToParse, '(',' '), ')','')`

Please note that this will only solve for parenthesis. Also, this is not a generic solution, it is just a patch for your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the pattern (with the numbers before 'test' is consistent across all the string, here is the sql for extracting the number:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 1]) > 0 
        THEN SUBSTRING([String 1], CHARINDEX(' ', [String 1], CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 1]))+1, CHARINDEX(' ', [String 1], CHARINDEX(' ', [String 1], CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 1]))+1) - CHARINDEX(' ', [String 1], CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 1]))-1)
        ELSE ''
    END AS [String 1],

    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 2]) > 0 
        THEN SUBSTRING([String 2], CHARINDEX(' ', [String 2])+1, CHARINDEX(' ', [String 2], CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 2])) - CHARINDEX(' ', [String 2])-1)
        ELSE ''
    END AS [String 2],

    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 3]) > 0 
        THEN SUBSTRING([String 3], CHARINDEX(' ', [String 3])+1, CHARINDEX(' ', [String 3], CHARINDEX(' Test ', [String 3])) - CHARINDEX(' ', [String 3])-1)
        ELSE ''
    END AS [String 3]
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using *tokenization* via XML and XQuery.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` clause creates XML for each row.
- XQuery FLWOR expression is checking for numeric values followed by
  the 'Test' word.
- $pos variable holds a position for each word.

**XML sample for ID=1**

```
<root>
  <r>Random</r>
  <r>Text</r>
  <r>3</r>
  <r>Random</r>
  <r>568</r>
  <r>Text</r>
  <r>5.5</r>
  <r>Test</r>
  <r>Random</r>
  <r>Text</r>
  <r>345</r>
</root>
```

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345'),
('Random Text 3 Test Text Random'),
('Random Text 777 Random Text');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT *
    , c.query('for $x in /root/r
        let $pos := count(/root/r[. << $x]) + 1
        return if (xs:decimal($x) instance of xs:decimal (: filter out non-digits :)
            and /root/r[$pos+1]/text()="Test") then $x
         else ()').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Ouput**

| ID | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345 | 5.5 |
| 2 | Random Text 3 Test Text Random | 3 |
| 3 | Random Text 777 Random Text |  |

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using a bit of `JSON` and the window function `lead() over()`

**Example**

```
DECLARE @YourTable Table (SomeCol VARCHAR(150));
INSERT @YourTable VALUES
('Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345'),
('Random Text 3 Test Text Random'),
('Random Text 777 Random Text');

Select A.SomeCol
      ,B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply (
                Select RetVal
                 From  (
                        Select RetVal = Value
                              ,NxtVal = lead(Value,1) over (order by [Key])
                         From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' )
                       ) B1
                 Where NxtVal='Test'
                   and try_convert(money,RetVal) is not null
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                                                   RetVal
Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345    5.5
Random Text 3 Test Text Random                            3
Random Text 777 Random Text                               NULL
```

Comment: Please try it for `('Random Text 777 Random Test')`, A check for a preceding numeric value is missing.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Ah, I see now.   Small tweak.   Added the trap.  Nice catch.