# SQL Query to extract the numbers before a specific word, including floating point numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have data like this:

```
String 1: 'Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345'
String 2: 'Random Text 3 Test Text Random'
String 3: 'Random Text 777 Random Text'
```

The output I expect is:

```
String 1: '5.5'
String 2: '3'
String 3: Nothing should output
```

And this works using the below code, provided from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75923063/10787041

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNumberBeforeStringTest
(
    @stringToParse varchar(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @testIndex INT = PATINDEX('%test%', @stringToParse);
    
    IF @testIndex = 0 RETURN NULL;

    DECLARE @s1 VARCHAR(100) = REVERSE(TRIM(SUBSTRING(@stringToParse, 0, @testIndex)))
    
    DECLARE @s2 VARCHAR(100) = REVERSE(TRIM(SUBSTRING(@s1, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @s1))))

    IF TRY_CAST(@s2 AS decimal) IS NULL
        RETURN NULL;

    RETURN @s2;
END
GO
```

I've noticed that when there is a string with brackets and a floating point the function doesn't work. An example would be:

```
String 4: 'Random Text (3.9 Test) Text Random'
```

Would it be possible to tell me how to edit the function to also be able to extract the number from a string that includes floating point numbers and a bracket, if this is having an affect on the function not working?

Thanks

Comment: Well you effectively have a string splitter that is splitting your string on a single space. There isn't a space before the number in your string 4 example. It would be finding (3.9 and trying to convert that string a decimal which will of course fail. That function has some other critical flaws. If you have the four characters "test" it will find only the first one, not the actual word "test". So say you have something like "4 softest 32 test" it will return NULL because it found "test" in "softest" and the rest of the logic is broken. This type of extraction is incredibly difficult.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove any brackets within the string using the REPLACE function, the S1 line would look like this instead:

```
DECLARE @s1 VARCHAR(100) = REVERSE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTRING(@stringToParse, 0, @testIndex)),'(',''),')',''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards due to use of the T-SQL `TRANSLATE()` function

No need in any UDF function.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345'),
('Random Text 3 Test Text Random'),
('Random Text 777 Random Text'),
('Random Text 777 Random Test'),
('Random Text (3.9 Test) Text Random');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT *
    , c.query('for $x in /root/r
        let $pos := count(/root/r[. << $x]) + 1
        return if (xs:decimal($x) instance of xs:decimal (: filter out non-digits :)
            and /root/r[$pos + 1]/text()="Test") then $x
         else ()').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(TRANSLATE(tokens,')(',SPACE(2)), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Random Text 3 Random 568 Text 5.5 Test Random Text 345 | 5.5 |
| 2 | Random Text 3 Test Text Random | 3 |
| 3 | Random Text 777 Random Text |  |
| 4 | Random Text 777 Random Test |  |
| 5 | Random Text (3.9 Test) Text Random | 3.9 |

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this alternative inline-table-valued function that works on a different premise.

It returns a table which will be considerably more performant when used for a set of rows.

The function:

```
create or alter function dbo.GetNumberBeforeStringTest(@str varchar(100))
returns table as
return select [value] = Iif(Try_Cast(n.v as decimal) is null, null, n.v)
from (select @str s)t
cross apply(values(NullIf(CharIndex('test', t.s), 0)-1))test(p)
cross apply(values(left(t.s, test.p)))l(p)
cross apply(values(patindex('%[^0-9.]%', Trim(Reverse(l.p)))))x(p)
cross apply(values(Right(l.p, x.p)))n(v);
```

And to use:

```
select t.col, v.[value]
from t
cross apply dbo.GetNumberBeforeStringTest(col)v;
```

And [a Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vZ-6xa2i)